# PHP mySQL search function join various field

Tags: php, mysql

The following code works to search for a surname from a table on the database. The field used to get the search is 'q'
  this is the query

```
 $sims = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM electors 
WHERE constituency = '$constituency'
 AND ward = '$ward' AND (surname RLIKE '$q') LIMIT 18");
```

However if the user enters any of the following or any combination of any of them put together in any order then that query will not work as it is only searching for the surname

> title, first_name, initial, surname ,suffix, roll no, email, telephone

I would like it to search for matching results from any of these fields without repeating a result.

This would mean that if, for example I typed in KNIGHT it would find me everyone with the surname KNIGHT, if I typed in ROBIN KNIGHT it would find me anyone with the first name ROBIN and surname KNIGHT or visa versa.

Comment: I'm sorry i can't understand you. Is there a question in your post?

Comment: Urgs, SQL injection at its best…

Comment: mysql extension is deprecated now: http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated

Comment: @ZombieHunter i wish people would read and learn before writing code, the web would be a much safer place that way :-)

Comment: @NicholasKing: Dream on... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just split them up into an `OR` statement:

```
$sims = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                     FROM `electors` 
                     WHERE `constituency` = '$constituency' 
                     AND `ward` = '$ward' 
                     AND (`title` RLIKE '$q' 
                         OR `first_name` RLIKE '$q' 
                         OR `initial` RLIKE '$q' 
                         OR `surname` RLIKE '$q' 
                         OR `suffix` RLIKE '$q' 
                         OR `roll_no` RLIKE '$q' 
                         OR `email` RLIKE '$q' 
                         OR `telephone` RLIKE '$q') 
                     LIMIT 18");
```

Not the most efficient of queries, but it'll get the job done.

Also, make sure to clean `$q` before doing that query. SQL injection is a major problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = str_replace(" ", "|", $q);

$sims = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM electors 
                     WHERE constituency = '$constituency'
                     AND ward = '$ward' 
                     AND (title RLIKE '$q'
                     OR first_name RLIKE '$q'
                     OR initial RLIKE '$q'
                     OR surname RLIKE '$q'
                     OR suffix RLIKE '$q'
                     OR roll_no RLIKE '$q'
                     OR email RLIKE '$q'
                     OR telephone RLIKE '$q')
                     LIMIT 18");
```

But really you should use mysqli and prepared statements.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM electors 
                         WHERE constituency = ?
                         AND ward = ?
                         AND (title RLIKE ?
                         OR first_name RLIKE ?
                         OR initial RLIKE ?
                         OR surname RLIKE ?
                         OR suffix RLIKE ?
                         OR roll_no RLIKE ?
                         OR email RLIKE ?
                         OR telephone RLIKE ?)
                         LIMIT 18");
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssssss', $constituency, $ward, 
                  $q, $q, $q, $q, $q, $q, $q, $q, $q);
$stmt->execute();
```