# PHP mySQL search for concatenated information across 2 fields

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I have a functioning mySQL search system.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM electors WHERE constituency = '$constituency' AND ward = '$ward' AND (surname LIKE '$q' OR first_name LIKE '$q') LIMIT 18");
```

I want to also search if the entered term (including space) would be a concatenation of `first_name ' ' surname.` How is this done.

Comment: offtopic: what happens if I search for `x'; DROP TABLE electors; --` do you prevent from SQL injection?

Comment: Do you often just ask the same question twice in a row? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222735/php-mysql-search-function-join-various-field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM electors WHERE constituency = '$constituency' AND ward = '$ward' AND (surname LIKE '$q' OR first_name LIKE '$q' OR CONCAT(first_name,' ',surname) LIKE '$q') LIMIT 18");
```

Which you may as well reduce down to:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM electors WHERE constituency = '$constituency' AND ward = '$ward' AND CONCAT(first_name,' ',surname) LIKE '%$q%' LIMIT 18");
```

Consider making this a full_name field in it's own right, then you can index it for speed reasons.